# How to track issues and PRs in many GitHub repositories

Tags: github

I work on many GitHub repositories ( > 10 ) with fairly small user bases. I sometimes lose track of issues of lesser used repositories.

Is there any way (either in GitHub, or using an external tool), of seeing all open PRs and issues in a list of repositories?

I know there is a "notifications" page, but this doesn't make it easy to find older, open, issues and PRs.

Comment: Why not utilize the API and build your own app?

Comment: What GitHub tier do you use? Potential answers differ, depending on whether you have GitHub Enterprise or not.

Comment: I've just got a standard github account

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the GitHub GraphQL API (https://docs.github.com/en/graphql).

Here's an example with random users' repos I jsut tested in GraphQl Explorer (https://docs.github.com/en/graphql/overview/explorer):

```
query {
  repo1: repository(owner: "amitukind", name: "architect3d") {
    issues(states: OPEN, first:100) {
      totalCount
      nodes {
        title
        url
      }
    }
    pullRequests(states: OPEN, first:100) {
      totalCount
      nodes {
        title
        url
      }
    }
  }
  repo2: repository(owner: "apernet", name: "OpenGFW") {
    issues(states: OPEN, first:100) {
      totalCount
      nodes {
        title
        url
      }
    }
    pullRequests(states: OPEN, first:100) {
      totalCount
      nodes {
        title
        url
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You can just use the explorer in your browser if you authenticate and allow it with permissions, or you could put the functionality into a custom app.

Answer (score 0):

This is a third party product, but one I use for a similar problem, but you could use GitKraken Workspaces to watch everything between multiple repos. I use GitKraken for git anyways, but it works well: https://www.gitkraken.com/solutions/workspaces

It allows me to see all the open PR's, Insights around development like throughput and merge rate, filter through issues (like being able to see all assigned to me across repos I have selected for a workspace) and more.

https://www.gitkraken.com/invite/bX2Nqsqr